# Where should I put javascript libraries in a Grails app?

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp

I have a couple of Javascript libraries of my own that do some nice prettyfying of my HTML pages and I want to include them in my gsp pages, particularly the landing page of my app.  I have tried putting them in `views` folder and `web-app/js` and `$APP_HOME/scripts` but when I load my index.gsp the scripts don't show up.

I have also tried a variety of alternatives in my code none of which work...

```
<script src="mylib.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/mylib.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/mylib.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'm sure there is a clever grails way of doing this on the fly, but I really just want a location where I can place some boilerplate JavaScript code that I can use in my app.  With convention over configuration in mind, what is the expected practice?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With your JS file at: `web-app/js/myLib.js`, putting `<g:javascript library="myLib" />` in your layout should I think be what you need.

Comment: see below: this is wrong. <g:javascript src="myLib" /> is correct.

Comment: You forgot js here @RickMangi. The correct way is: `<g:javascript src="myLib.js" />`

Comment: What happens when you build and deploy your app ? Is the JavaScript automatically packaged ???

Answer (score 23):

You should probably NOT use `<g:javascript library="myLib" />` as that is meant to be used as a way to make AJAX calls library (scriptaculous, dojo, yahoo, jquery) indifferent.  See [grails javascript](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/javascript.html).  Instead use `<g:javascript src="myLib.js" />`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways by which you can include JS file and JS library like scriptaculous

```
// actually imports '/app/js/myscript.js'
<g:javascript src="myscript.js" />

// imports all the necessary js for the scriptaculous library
<g:javascript library="scriptaculous" />

<g:javascript>alert('hello')</g:javascript>
```

Refer : http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer...

If I use this tag in my gsp (rather than a straightforward javascript reference)

```
<g:javascript library="mylib" />
```

Then when I look at the generated page source it refers to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myapp/js/mylib.js"></script>
```

This corresponds to the folder `web-app/js`, so I dropped my script library in there and it works fine.  The breakthrough was for me to a) rename my index.html to index.gsp and b) use the `g:javascript` tag.

Comment: yep exactly - I need to type more quickly :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `<g:javascript src="myscript.js" />` and place your script in `web-app/js/myscript.js`

For full detail and examples for both your own external scripts, in-line code and libraries see http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/javascript.html.

Comment: What about in grails 3 ?